# How do you set Left and Center Align when using a SQL insert?

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I am inserting new rows into a dataGridView Table.  I have a sql sting that looks like this.

```
sql = @"INSERT INTO " + myNameRange + " VALUES ("+rowString+")";
```

My method that works looks like this.

```
public static void inSertRow(string myNameRange, string rowString)
    {
        string sql = null;

        sql = @"INSERT INTO " + myNameRange + " VALUES ("+rowString+")";

        if (myCommand == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR :: dfsdfsdf");
        }

        myCommand.CommandText = sql;
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

When I bring in "rowString" into the VALUES portion of the sql string, my question is;

Is there a way to set the "justification" / alignment of the information in that cell?  Can it be done within the sql string?

So if my rowString of information coming in is ('city', 'state', 'zip') and I want city and state to be left aligned in the cell, but zip to be centered aligned.. can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: no. it's not possible. databases store data. You're talking about a PRESENTATION problem. that's not the database's job. that's up to your CLIENT code.

Comment: Don't insert data to SQL like that read about [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formatting the way data looks is not the job of a database.  When you insert your data you want to keep it a simple as possible.  The time to format your data is when you read the data from the database.

You may want to justify your data centrally in one application but not in another.  However the value stored in the database remains the same.

If you want to remove leading or trailing spaces use the `ltrim` and `rtrim` functions.